# More efficient compareTo algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, compareto

I'm using Collections.sort to sort a ArrayList of objects, and I want to see if there is a more efficient compareTo method for what I'm trying to do.

Here's the method:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Song s) {
    if (runningTime > s.runningTime) {
        return -1;
    } else if (runningTime < s.runningTime) {
        return 1;
    }
    int lastCmp = title.compareTo(s.title);
    return (lastCmp != 0 ? lastCmp : composer.compareTo(s.composer));
}
```

If anyone could suggest a more efficient method (i.e. quicker runtime) I would be very grateful.

Comment: I don't understand what your question title has to do with the question you asked?

Comment: @Vincent Ramdhanie oops sorry mate, I forgot to change the title name from a previous question I was going to write. My apologies.

Comment: any improvement would be insignificant. your method seems fine to me.

Comment: A little improvement is to avoid calling String compareTo and put the comparison in the body of your method.

Comment: As I have pointed out before, you really need to check you want to sort by the song's runtime rather than title. Correctness is more important than speed. ;) Also you are unlikely to have so many Songs that it will matter.  The most you can save on one million songs will be a few milli-seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like MeBigFatGuy said, any improvement is insignificant, but I think you can still clean up the code a bit to reduce unnecessary if-else condition. My two cents.

```
public int compareTo(Song s) {
    if (runningTime != s.runningTime) {
        return s.runningTime - runningTime;
    }
    else {
        int lastCmp = title.compareTo(s.title);
        return (lastCmp != 0 ? lastCmp : composer.compareTo(s.composer));
    }
}
```

Comment: Else is unnecessary after return

Comment: This doesn't work properly if the running time is double, and the difference in running time is less than a second. Worst is that the results will be inconsistent; you can have a = b and b = c but a < c.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the priority of song ordering is fixed (running time; title if running times are the same; composer if running times and titles are the same), then there's not much you can do better. If the priorities are not fixed, then perhaps testing on composer before title may speed things up a bit; it depends on your actual data. I'd keep the test on running times first, because that is always going to be faster than string comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me as well. If you're running into performance problems, you might check if you're sorting too often. Not sure if Collections.sort is sensitive to this by now, but you might gain sth if you don't resort an already sorted list after inserting only a few songs

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how long it takes to read a property value, it might be a **tiny** bit quicker to store runningTime and s.runningTime into local variables first. So on average, instead of reading them 1.5 or more times per call, you'd only read them once per call.